# Class 'Proxy\Factory' not found PHP error although file exists

Tags: php, symfony

I downloaded this lib, extracted it and uploaded it to my php webspace: https://github.com/jenssegers/php-proxy

Also, I added a new index.php file with this content from the example included to the lib archive:

```
<?php

use Proxy\Factory;
use Proxy\Response\Filter\RemoveEncodingFilter;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Create the proxy factory.
$proxy = Factory::create();

// Add a response filter that removes the encoding headers.
$proxy->addResponseFilter(new RemoveEncodingFilter());

// Create a Symfony request based on the current browser request.
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

// Forward the request and get the response.
$response = $proxy->forward($request)->to('http://example.com');

// Output response to the browser.
$response->send();

?>
```

The file structure looks like this (collapsed):

[image: Folder hierachy collcapsed]

Expanded:

[image: Expanded folder hierarchy]

But when I run the script, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Proxy\Factory' not found in index.php on line 10

Line 12 would be this:

```
$proxy = Factory::create();
```

Why does this happen? Shouldn't `use Proxy\Factory;` properly include the file Factory.php?

---

**Update:** The content of autoload.php is this:

```
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit60f173139b462a85925faf1b40913ce6::getLoader();
```

Comment: Why is `index.php` inside `vendor` dir? Have you tried to use composer? Seems like your autoload does not work, I suggest `$proxy = Proxy\Factory::create()` will fail too. As of _"Shouldn't `use Proxy\Factory;` properly include the file Factory.php?"_: PHP namespaces *are not a way to include files, those are for organizing code and resolving naming conflicts* so there's likely a problem with your autoload.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your folder structure. Are the Symfony and Proxy directories in vendor? Is index.php in the root of your project?

Comment: @НЛО Nah, it just looks like as if index.php is in vendor folder in that screenshot. I added another screenshot with all folder collapsed. As you can see, index.php is in root.

Comment: @scheisse_minelli I added another screenshot with folders collapsed, I think that makes things clearer.

Comment: What is in your `vendor/autoload.php` script? Also, why not load it with Composer directly into the `vendor` directory? Composer should handle the autoloading setup for you, if you do it right.

Comment: Install with composer: Bring up a shell, `cd` to your root, and run this command: `composer require jenssegers/proxy` (This is assuming you've [installed composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).) How you've installed it manually, the autoloader isn't going to recognize it, AFAICT.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I can't do that. My hoster is just a simple php webspace provider which I can access via ftp and upload files. No shell, no composer. So, what I basically did was, use composer on my local computer and then upload the whole thing via ftp.

Comment: The alternative is to do your composer package installs/development locally, so you can use composer, then upload the project to your server when it's ready. In general you shouldn't be mucking with files in `vendor`, so this technically shouldn't be an issue. The `Proxy` package should be in `vendor`, though, typically with the package vendor first, e.g., `/vendor/jenssegers/php-proxy`.

Comment: When I run `composer require jenssegers/proxy` locally, I get the following path: `/vendor/jenssegers/proxy/[src/Proxy.php]`

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes, you're right. I had to install composer and use `require` instead of just copying. Now it's nagging about some timezone configuration in php.init so I'll have to look into that..

Comment: I use the [Scotchbox Vagrant box](https://box.scotch.io/), and have had to set that several times (when I install a new one). Here's how it works on that: http://pastebin.com/k3PjNwPq

Comment: @JaredFarrish I got it running now locally. When I open localhost:8000 it shows up the page correctly. But I assume that this will not work on an ordinary php webhosting service? They only offer apache with php on port 80.. There is no way I can start a Symphony server.

Comment: The port is associated to how your server software is configured (apache), unless you mean the Proxy system you're trying to use listening on 8000. You can check the class config and see if there's a way to change that I guess, but you would have to check with the service provider to see how to enable that if it's required, and if it's possible. You might look at something like Pagoda Box, which allows you to run a free (but not very powerful) box for software development, but also gives you shell access.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Alright Jared, thanks a lot for you help. I think I can take on from here alone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work. I had totally messed up the Symfony project structure, so here is what I did to get it to work:

Run in shell (on Mac OS X):

```
$ symfony new proxy 2.7
$ cd proxy
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ php composer.phar require jenssegers/proxy
$ sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

In `/etc/php.ini` search for timezone and remove the colon in front. Then set `date.timezone = "Europe/Berlin"`.

Then I edit this file: `src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php` and add my code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Proxy\Factory;
use Proxy\Response\Filter\RemoveEncodingFilter;

require '/Users/me/dev/symphony/proxy/vendor/autoload.php';

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        /*
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..'),
        ));
        */
        // Create the proxy factory.
        $proxy = Factory::create();

        // Add a response filter that removes the encoding headers.
        $proxy->addResponseFilter(new RemoveEncodingFilter());

        // Create a Symfony request based on the current browser request.
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();

        // Forward the request and get the response.
        $response = $proxy->forward($request)->to('http://example.com');

        // Output response to the browser.
        $response->send();
    }
}
```

Then just run the server:

```
$ php app/console server:run
```

And open `localhost:8000`.

Comment: Port 8000 here is only so that it doesn't interfere with whatever may be listening on port 80. You shouldn't have an issue with this once you deploy to your webserver, since the port is configured for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `index.php` one level up in directory structure: `require vendor/autoload.php` inside `vendor` dir looks too strange, it is not very likely you (and anyone) would have `vendor` directory inside `vendor` directory

Comment: Nah, it just looks like as if index.php is in vendor folder in that screenshot. I added another screenshot with all folder collapsed. As you can see, index.php is in root.